# getaddrinfo versus inet_pton

Tags: c++, sockets

Hopefully there is a Winsock expert out there who can answer my question.  As the title suggests, is there any case where `inet_pton` would be better over `getaddrinfo`?  I mean, the class I am writing current checks for dotted-decimal and calls `inet_pton` and if URL it calls `getaddrinfo`.  `getaddrinfo` by itself will resolve both URL and dotted so it seem redundant.

It would make for slightly less code just to use `getaddrinfo` and drop the extra case of handling dotted separate.

Should I just use one call to do it all or handle each case differently?

Thanks

edit: I should have mentioned this all happens in a class constructor for a socket wrapper.  The constructor takes a string that can be either a URL or dotted (ipv4 or 6).  If `getaddrinfo` just calls `inet_pton` then my code would be cleaner by just using `getaddrinfo`

Comment: inet_pton parses an IP address string; getaddrinfo looks up a domain name or parses an IP address string. Do you want to look up domains? If yes, getaddrinfo, if no, inet_pton

Comment: I don't know if there is some special Winsock specific reason to do otherwise, but in POSIX at least I see no reason to not simply use `getaddrinfo` directly.

Comment: @eerorika it is the same for WinSock, too.